# How can I implement comparision for custom datatypes?

Tags: haskell

I have to compare people only by date of birth (I shouldn't compare their names)and if the dates of birth are equal, it should return true, but why do I get false in both cases?

```
module Main where

data Person a = Person a a (Data Int Month) deriving (Show,Eq)

data Month = January | February | March | April | May | June | July deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Data a b = Data (a, b, a) deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Data a b) where
  Data (a1, b1, c1) < Data (a2, b2, c2) =
    (c1 < c2)
      || ((c1 == c2) && (b1 < b2))
      || ((c1 == c2) && (b1 == b2) && (a1 < a2))
  Data (a1, b1, c1) <= Data (a2, b2, c2) =
    (c1 < c2)
      || ((c1 == c2) && (b1 < b2))
      || ((c1 == c2) && (b1 == b2) && (a1 < a2))
      || ((c1 == c2) && (b1 == b2) && (a1 == a2))

instance (Ord a) => Ord (Person a) where
  (Person _ _ d1) < (Person _ _ d2) = d1 < d2
  (Person _ _ d1) <= (Person _ _ d2) = d1 < d2 || d1 == d2

m1 = Person "Ivanov" "Ivan" (Data (4, February, 2022))
m2 = Person "Ivanova" "Inna" (Data (4, February, 2022))

main = do
  print (m1 == m2) 
  print (m2 >= m1)
```

Comment: Note that Haskell tuples are already lexicographically ordered, so you can define `Data (a1, b1, c1) <= Data (a2, b2, c2)` as `(c1, b1, a1) <= (c2, b2, a2)` (or do the analogous for `compare`). In this way you no longer need to use all those `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Proposal: name your comparison functions something other than `(==)` and `(>=)`. The real deal -- the ones that compare all fields, and can be written by the compiler -- are likely to be useful operations from time to time anyway, so you'll likely want both variants. And if you have both, by far the less surprising thing would be for the standard names to do the standard thing, and a nonstandard name chosen for the nonstandard thing.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend first making your type a *record* for easier accessibility and understandability:

```
data Person a = Person {
    longFirstName :: a
  , shortFirstName :: a
  , birthDate :: Data Int Month
  } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Then, you can lift any comparison operator on birth-dates to a comparison operator on `Person`s, using the [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) combinator:

```
  ((==)`on`birthDate) m1 m2
  ((<)`on`birthDate) m1 m2
```

If you need this specifically for sorting a list, you can use [`sortOn birthDate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) instead of the standard `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

`m1 == m2` is using the generated `Eq` instance, which of course checks all fields. It never uses your `Ord` instance at all, and once it determines the names are different it doesn't bother checking whether the dates are the same.

`m2 >= m1` does use `Ord`, and your `Ord` instance for `Data` seems fine, although more complicated than necessary: you don't need to supply anything more than `<=` or `compare`, so all the work going into `<` is just adding places where you could make a mistake (although, again, you didn't).

The problem is that your `Ord (Person a)` instance is wrong. It doesn't use your clever `<=` implementation either! Instead it tries `<`, and then falls back to `==` which, again, is the default instance.

So if you want to be able to compare these things by just their birthdate, you need an `Eq` instance that participates in the charade. But also, consider not encoding this kind of "partial comparison" in the canonical `Eq` and `Ord` instances. [The `Eq` class recommends extensionality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), roughly meaning two objects which are equal should be indistinguishable by other means. Instead, just define e different top-level function like `bornBefore` that compares people by birth date. If you need an Ord instance to give your types to some library function like `sort`: most of them have an overload that lets you specify the comparison function explicitly, like `sortBy`. If that option isn't available and you really need an `Ord` instance that behaves like this, consider a newtype wrapper around your canonical types.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand yet what's wrong with the `Ord (Person a)` instance. It looks to me like it falls back to `(==)`, but only on the date field. What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at the [source for `Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.9.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#Ord), I think I see now what the issue is, but it's a bit subtle. Namely: the default implementation of `(>=)` does not immediately call `(<=)`, but rather goes through `compare`; and the default implementation of `compare` does an equality check first. So even though the methods implemented in the original `Ord` instance did the right thing, the default implementations didn't! (And `<` isn't used at all, so that seems like an imprecision in this answer.)